Which mobile app Engagement platform gives event timestamps?
I have tried out Clevertap. It doesn't have the following features:

I can't select date range for events
Cant get Session duration
Customisation for flows cannot to be done
There is no timestamp recorded for Event

Do you know if there are other app engagement platforms which does these ? Any suggestions please lemme know
